# Value value is not a member of sbt.SettingKey under SBT 0.12?

Tags: sbt

I saw this code for adding profiles to a SBT project, but it doesn't compile for me in Scala 2.9.2.

```
val ProfileDev = config("dev") extend(Runtime)
val ProfileQA  = config("qa") extend(Runtime)

val root = (project in file(".")).
  configs(ProfileDev, ProfileQA). // add config here!
  settings( 
    name := "helloworld",
    ....
  ).
  settings(inConfig(ProfileDev)(Classpaths.configSettings ++ Defaults.configTasks ++ Defaults.resourceConfigPaths ++ Seq(
    unmanagedResourceDirectories += {baseDirectory.value / "src" / configuration.value.name / "resources"}
  )): _*).
  settings(inConfig(ProfileQA)(Classpaths.configSettings ++ Defaults.configTasks ++ Defaults.resourceConfigPaths ++ Seq(
    unmanagedResourceDirectories += {baseDirectory.value / "src" / configuration.value.name / "resources"}
  )): _*)
```

This is the error I face

```
Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/robin/workspace/active_projects/Republiq/server/project/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes...
[error] /home/robin/workspace/active_projects/Republiq/server/project/Build.scala:121: value value is not a member of sbt.SettingKey[java.io.File]
[error]       unmanagedResourceDirectories += {baseDirectory.value / "src" / configuration.value.name / "resources"}
[error]                                                      ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess (from the compilation path `Republiq/server/project/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes`) that you use SBT **0.12**.

It's only since **0.13** when the support for the macro `value` was introduced - see [New task/setting syntax](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Community/ChangeSummary_0.13.0.html#new-task-setting-syntax) in **0.13.0 Changes** document.

Upgrade to SBT 0.13 or rewrite the part with `value`.